# System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying create and save the password both in salt and hash while I'm trying to insert user password in database. While I'm clicking the register button it's shows the following error.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null.
```

Below I've added my code of registration page.

```
public class GenerateHash
{
    public string CreateSalt(int SaltSize)
    {
        var rng = new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] Salt = new byte[SaltSize];
        rng.GetBytes(Salt);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Salt);
    }

    public string GenarateHash(string UserPassword, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UserPassword + salt);
        byte[] PasswordHash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(PasswordHash);
    }

    protected void Regist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateHash HashAndSalt = new GenerateHash();
        string GetSalt = HashAndSalt.CreateSalt(10);
        string hashString = HashAndSalt.GenarateHash(Password.Text, GetSalt);
        string username = UserName.Text;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into [User](UserName, PasswordHashed, Salt) values(" + "@UserName, @PasswordHashed, @Salt)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordHashed", hashString);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salt", GetSalt);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("Login  .aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set any break points? It would appear you are failing to get the connection string from your config file

Comment: Can you give the snippet of your config where you are pulling this connection string?

Comment: Figured out. Thank you ;0

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: For the null exception, it would have to be the key does not exist in the configuration.

Comment: the connection string was wrong that is the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the connection string name in your web.config file and see if it matches the `ConnectionString` in your code.

For example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=saha;UID=root;PASSWORD=abc123;max pool size=50000000; Allow User Variables=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

So in the above code change the `name="connstr"` to  `name="connectionString"`. I think that should resolve your issue.
Hope it helps.